# Show rich Fancy box popup when marker is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-markers, fancybox-2

I want to display some information and some images  when a google marker is clicked. I'm using **fancy box** to do that but is it possible to display such informations with fancy box because as i know fancy box is used to display images only.

So my question is : **is it possible to display a rich fancy box popup ( using html tags maybe ) ?**

and if so how ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is YES.

With fancybox, beside of images, you can display HTML elements (inline HTML content), SWF movies, Iframes (external html documents) and also Ajax requests, PDFs, google maps, youtube or vimeo videos, etc.

Visit http://fancybox.net/ for demos of such content (main page) if you want to use the v1.3.4 (see the source code of those examples here http://fancybox.net/js/web.js)

... or visit http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples if you want to use v2.x (html and js code is on the page)